# How to find a new equidistant vector, given five existing vectors?

Tags: python, numpy, vector, vectorization, linear-algebra

I have vectors v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, with 100 dim, I need to find a center vector, that will have equal distance with each.

**Uptdate:** Looking at [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3203273/how-to-find-a-new-equidistant-vector-given-5-existing-vectors?noredirect=1#comment6590954_3203273) from Mathmatics, is there a way to implement the solution in Numpy/Python?

Comment: Do you always have exactly 5 points and 100 dimensions?

Comment: @Alex bGoode, 100 yes,  but not five,  it varies from group to another so its 2 to 10

Comment: Your title and the question do not match. Are you looking for the mean of these vectors or a vector that is equidistant from all your points (of those there are infinitely many).

Comment: @AlexbGoode  yes, a vector that is equal distant from all points or all vectors. so each vector is n=100 dimension, so i am looking for a 100 dim vector set in equal distance

Comment: I think this question might be better suited for [Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/). Once you found an algorithm you can update this question to ask about its implementation.

Comment: I'd second that statement. If your problem is with the math of this, then mathematica.stackexchange.com is a better place to ask. If you want a Python implementation thereof, you will have to show any effort yourself though and ask specific questions concerning specific problems with the use of Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything depends on how vectors are presented in Python.

Lets v1, v2, ... , v5  are presented as lists of values. Each list has len = 100.

In this case I would do the following:

```
np.vstack([v1, v2, v3, v4, v5]).mean(axis=1)
```

If vectors are already composed as 5x100 array, e.g. `arr`, `arr.shape=(5, 100)`,
you can get the solution as follows:

```
arr.mean(axis=1)
```

EDIT: [the question was changed/clarified]

To get equidistant vector (x) look at the following code snippet I just wrote:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import least_squares

np.random.seed(10)
vector_as_rows = np.random.rand(5, 100)

def Q(x, vs=vector_as_rows):
    d = x[-1]
    result = list()
    for v in vs:
        result.append(np.linalg.norm(v-x[:-1])- d)
    result.append(0)
    return result

res = least_squares(Q, np.random.rand(101)).x

for v in vector_as_rows:
    print("Dist between x and v[k]: ", np.linalg.norm(v - res[:-1]))
```

So, `res[:-1]` (len = 100) is equidistant to all `v[i]`; `res[-1]` is distance value.

```
Dist between x and v[k]:  2.530871535402036
Dist between x and v[k]:  2.530871505069009
Dist between x and v[k]:  2.530871545163243
Dist between x and v[k]:  2.5308715299141045
Dist between x and v[k]:  2.5308715309178402
```

I suspected that the problem has analytical solution; I just implemented
one of the possible ways to solve undetermined linear system from
the link you provided.

```
A = (vector_as_rows[0] - vector_as_rows[1:]) * 2
res = np.dot(np.linalg.pinv(A), (vector_as_rows[0]**2 - vector_as_rows[1:]**2).sum(axis=1))
for v in vector_as_rows:
    print("Dist between x and v[k]: ", np.linalg.norm(v - res))
```

And result is:

```
Dist between x and v[k]:  5.569005123058085
Dist between x and v[k]:  5.569005123058085
Dist between x and v[k]:  5.569005123058084
Dist between x and v[k]:  5.569005123058084
Dist between x and v[k]:  5.569005123058085
```

I used `np.linalg.pinv`, that is Moore-Penrose pseudo-inversion. Using it I got a minimal length solution for the undetermined linear system. So, obtained vector `res` has smallest norm of all possible solutions for this problem.

Comment: thanks for that, but I get a 5-dim vector, I was looking for a similar dim(=100) vector that has same distance to each of vectors from v1 to v5? I might not be wording it right in the question, but couldnt be a vector of similar dimension that is center for all?

Comment: @bubble so `vector_as_rows` are the vectors in the question, but what is `res`? is the the solution vector, therefore it remains in the code and it changes per the input (`vector_as_rows`)?

Comment: res is a solution vector; I updated the post and implemented the solution from the link you provided